# how can I make the hover respond?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me why the hover not activ when i hover on caption nothing happends

```
 .portfolio .caption{ 
      display: none;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: white;
      width: 350px;
      z-index: 2;
     transform: translateY(-53px); 
    }
     .portfolio .caption h4{ 
    padding: 10px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    }
     .portfolio .caption p{
     padding-left: 10px; 
    color: var(--main-color); 
    }
     .portfolio img:hover .caption{
     display: block;
     }
```

Comment: You can't hover over `display: none` element becasue it is not displayed.

Comment: Can you please include your HTML code?

Comment: Please share your html code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `opacity` instead of `display`

If the element has `display: none;` then it's gone. That also means that you can't hover over it. But you can use `opacity`

`opacity: 0;` is like `display: none;` but the `opacity: 0;` is just transparent. That means that you can still hover over it.

You can also use a `transition` like `transition: ease-in-out .2s;`. This will give the `opacity` element a transition which you **CAN'T** use with `display`

Here's the CSS:

```
.portfolio .caption{
   opacity: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translateY(-53px);
}
.portfolio .caption h4{
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.portfolio .caption p{
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: var(--main-color);
}
.portfolio .caption:hover{
       opacty: 1;
}
```

---

### Here's an example with the difference. There's also a transition, you can remove it

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#display {
  display: none;
}

#opacity {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out .2s; /* Just a transition, you can remove it  */
}

/* Hovering over the elements */

#display:hover {
  display: block;
}

#opacity:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p id="display">Display</p>
<p id="opacity">Opacity</p>

<label>Hover above and you will see that the display is gone but the opacity is just transparent</label>
```

---

##### If you inspect the opacity element then you can see that the so called hitboxes are still there. The display element is completely gone

[image]

Comment: yes thats true i forgot that i cannot hover over a hidden element but the question here why the hover isnot responding when i set img identefier to it ? i mean although i use img element and its not hidden it also not working ex below

Comment: Hi @ayaabdelhakeem, could you please edit your question instead of commenting the code? It's really hard to read that

Comment: yes sure

``` 
.portfolio .caption{
   display: none;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translateY(-53px);
}
.portfolio .caption h4{
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.portfolio .caption p{
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: var(--main-color);
}
.portfolio img:hover .caption{
       display: block;
}
```

Comment: ooh i donnot know why it still apper as a comment while i use``` but to clarify this i was referring to this line   hope itis simple to read

 .portfolio img:hover .caption{ display: block; }

Comment: @ayaabdelhakeem i meant could you edit it in your **QUESTION**, not the comment :) There's a little `Edit` button under your Question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `display`, use `opacity`.

If you use `display:none:` you cannot hover it becuase it isn't there.

But if you use `opacity:0;`, the element is still there but transparent. So you can still hover it.

```
   .portfolio .caption{
   display: none; <------- remove
    opacity:0; <---------- add
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translateY(-53px);
}
.portfolio .caption h4{
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.portfolio .caption p{
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: var(--main-color);
}
.portfolio .caption:hover{
    display: block; <------ remove
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alterative solution you can target `hover` of parent element like this

```
.portfolio:hover .caption {
           display: block;
    }
```

Full css code

```
.portfolio .caption{
   display: none;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translateY(-53px);
}
.portfolio .caption h4{
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.portfolio .caption p{
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: var(--main-color);
}
.portfolio:hover .caption {
       display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code wont work because you set ".caption" to `display: none;` so you can't hover over an element that is hidden.

One possible solution is to create another element, and when you hover over that element you can change the ".caption" display. Example below.

```css
.portfolio .caption {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 350px;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateY(-53px);
}

.portfolio .caption h4 {
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.portfolio .caption p {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: var(--main-color);
}

.show-caption:hover~.portfolio .caption {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="show-caption">
  Show caption
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="caption">
    <h4>Caption Title</h4>
    <p>This caption text is only visible on hover</p>
  </div>
</div>
```